# how to increase the scroll area without increasing the size of List-view in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, scroll

I have a Listview which will be displaying only one item at a time, 
How can I increase the touch area for scrolling list items?

**Increasing height of ListView will not be an option because it will show more than 1 item at a time.**

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what adapter you are using, but typically you want to create a custom adapter and a custom layout for a listview item and inflating this layout in the getView-method of your adapter. Then you can customize the size of each item in the ListView. Here is a quite nice [tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter) for a more in-depth explanation.

Hope that will help you!

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. Currently i am using the custom adapter for inflating the row in listview. Increasing size of the each item is not an option since it will increase the space between them.

Comment: @NavaneethKR Hmm I'm afraid I don't understand your question then. With "touch area", you do not mean the size of an item in the ListView? Could you clarify a little?